# Walker class not found error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am using wordpress for the first time. I am trying to incorperated the walker class into my project which is located at

```
D:\wamp\www\SgsOnline\wp-content\themes\storefront\inc\functions\walker.php
```

I've included my class in my functions as

```html
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/functions/walker.php';
```

And I am trying to call it in my header like :

```html
 function storefront_primary_navigation() {
  ?>
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation " role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Navigation', 'storefront' ); ?>">
  <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-navigation" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'storefront_menu_toggle_text', __( 'Navigation', 'storefront' ) ) ); ?></button>
   <?php
   wp_nav_menu(
    array(
     'theme_location' => 'primary',
     'container_class' => 'primary-navigation',
     'menu_class'=>'nav navbar-nav navbar-left nav-tabs',
     'walker' => new Walker_Nav_Primary()
     )
   );
   ?>
  </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
  <?php
 }
```

But I am getting a error :

> Fatal error: Class 'Walker_Nav_Primary' not found in
>   D:\wamp\www\SgsOnline\wp-content\themes\storefront\inc\structure\header.php
>   on line 65

This is oblivious wrong because it is looking in the wrong place for the class.
If anyone has any experience with this would be great

Regards

UPDATE

here is the class code

```html
<?php 
/* Collection of walker classes*/
class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_menu {

 function start_lvl( &$output, $depth){ //ul
  $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth );
  $submenu = ($depth > 0) 'sub-menu' : ''; //Detect if the lvls is a submenu
  $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
 }


/*
 function end_lvl(){ // close ul

 }



 Not used at the moment 

 function start_el(){ // li, a, span

 }

 function end_el(){ // closing  li, a, span

 }
*/

}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it appears that file path is incorrect. `/` is unix directory separator but you need to use `\` for Windows.

```
$path_elements = array(get_template_directory(), 'inc', 'functions', 'walker.php');
require join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , $path_elements);
```

`Walker_Nav_Primary` has a syntax error in shorthand if-else statement (missing question mark after logical expression).

```
$submenu = ($depth > 0) ? 'sub-menu' : '';
```

Comment: Yes I tried this as well still no joy . I have added my class code above also

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is how you reference your walker...

```
'walker' => new Walker_Nav_Primary()
```

should just be...

```
'walker' => new Walker_Nav_Primary
```

no () needed.

If there was an issue with how you include your walker.php file that would error first as functions.php is run before your header.php.